# jQuery: this no funciona como espero

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- Información (con clasificación) -->

    <div class="mr-3"> <?php echo '<span class="numero" data-contador="'.$contador.'">'.$contador.'</span>'; ?> </div> <!-- Clasificación -->

    <div class="col informacion"> <!-- Información -->
        <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos"><span class="titulos cancion">'.$titulo_cancion.'</span> de&nbsp<span><a class="autor-recopilatorio" href="'.$enlace_rym.'" target="_blank">'.$nombre_autor.'</a></span></div>'; ?></div>
        <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos">('.$nombre_ciudad.', '.$nombre_pais.')</div>'; ?></div>
        <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos">Incluida en su '.$tipo.'&nbsp<span class="titulos">'.$titulo_disco.'</span>&nbsp'.$ano_disco.'</div>'; ?></div>
        <div class="row "><?php echo '<span class="votos">'.$votos_facebook.'&nbsp</span>'; if($votos_facebook == 1) echo 'voto'; else echo 'votos'; ?></div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row"> <!-- Sistema de votación -->

    <span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2">

        <?php 

            if($_SESSION['conectado']) for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
            {
                echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$id_cancion.'" value="'.$i.'"';
                echo ($i == $nota) ? " checked><i></i>" : "><i></i>";  
            }

        ?>

    </span>

</div>
```

Que está incluida en una llamada a la base de datos, de manera que se repite n veces, las necesarias para mostrar todas las canciones que es menester.

Bien, he hecho el siguiente script de jQuery para atrapar ciertos valores:

```
$(function() 
{
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function()
    {
        var voto = $(this).val();
        var idCancion = $(this).attr('name');
        var cancion = $(this).parents('.row').siblings('.row').find('.cancion').html();
        var autor = $(this).parents('.row').siblings('.row').find('.autor-recopilatorio').html();

        console.log(idCancion);
        console.log(voto);
        console.log(cancion);
        console.log(autor);
    })
});
```

El problema es que funciona para `idCancion` y `voto` pero no para `cancion` y `autor`, dado que siempre me devuelve los mismos valores, los correspondientes a la primera canción que se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Atrapa los valores que quiero, pero parece que el `this` no está funcionando como espero, ¿a qué se puede deber? ¿Quizá usar `type="radio"` es demasiado inespecífico? La verdad es que es el único radiobotón que aparece en la web...

EDITO2: El archivo al completo:

```
<?php   

    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    $filas = array();

    while($filas[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados));

    array_pop($filas);

    if($_SESSION['id_usuario']) 
    {
        $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

        $sql = "SELECT id_cancion, nota FROM votan WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

        $filas2 = array();

        while($filas2[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)); 

        mysqli_close($conexion);

        $provisional = array();

        foreach($filas as $clave => $fila) 
        {
            foreach($filas2 as $clave2 => $fila2) if($fila['id_cancion'] == $fila2['id_cancion']) $fila['nota'] = $fila2['nota'];

            array_push($provisional, $fila);
        }

        $filas = $provisional;
    }

    foreach($filas as $clave => $fila) 
    {
        $enlace_youtube = $fila['enlace_youtube'];
        $titulo_cancion = utf8_encode($fila['titulo_cancion']);
        $id_autor = utf8_encode($fila['id_autor']);
        $nombre_autor = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_autor']);
        $enlace_rym = $fila['enlace_rym'];
        $nombre_ciudad = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_ciudad']);
        $nombre_pais = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_pais']);
        $votos_facebook = $fila['votos_facebook'];
        $tipo = $fila['tipo'];
        $titulo_disco = utf8_encode($fila['titulo_disco']);
        $ano = $fila['ano'];
        $id_cancion = $fila['id_cancion'];
        $nota = $fila['nota'];

        $inicio = strpos($enlace_youtube, "watch?v=");
        $enlace_youtube = substr_replace($enlace_youtube, "embed/", $inicio, 8);

        if(strpos($nombre_autor, ", The")) $nombre_autor = "The ".substr($nombre_autor, 0, strpos($nombre_autor, ", The"));

        $decada = substr($ano, 0, 3)."0s";

        if(strpos($titulo_disco, "/")) $nombre_foto = substr($titulo_disco, 0, strpos($titulo_disco, "/"));
        elseif(strpos($titulo_disco, ":")) $nombre_foto = substr($titulo_disco, 0, strpos($titulo_disco, ":"));
        else $nombre_foto = $titulo_disco;

        if($condicion == true) $ano_disco = '('.$ano.')';
        else $ano_disco = null;

        $contador++;

        echo '<div class="row contenedor-youtube pt-4"><iframe class="youtube" width="575" height="323.5" src='.$enlace_youtube.' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>'; #Vídeo

        ?>

        <div class="row pt-2"> <!-- Portada, información y sistema de votación -->

            <div class="contenedor-portada mr-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-imagen"> <!-- Portada -->
                <?php echo '<img class="portada" src="imagenes/'.$decada.'/'.$ano.'/'.$nombre_foto.'.jpg" width="150" height="150">'; ?>
            </div>

            <div id="modal-imagen" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <img id="modal-imagen-in" style="width: 100%">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col"> <!-- Información y sistema de votación -->

                <div class="row"> <!-- Información (con clasificación) -->

                    <div class="mr-3"> <?php echo '<span class="numero" data-contador="'.$contador.'">'.$contador.'</span>'; ?> </div> <!-- Clasificación -->

                    <div class="col informacion"> <!-- Información -->
                        <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos"><span id="'.$id_cancion.'" class="titulos cancion">'.$titulo_cancion.'</span> de&nbsp<span id="'.$id_autor.'"><a class="autor-recopilatorio" href="'.$enlace_rym.'" target="_blank">'.$nombre_autor.'</a></span></div>'; ?></div>
                        <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos">('.$nombre_ciudad.', '.$nombre_pais.')</div>'; ?></div>
                        <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos">Incluida en su '.$tipo.'&nbsp<span class="titulos">'.$titulo_disco.'</span>&nbsp'.$ano_disco.'</div>'; ?></div>
                        <div class="row "><?php echo '<span class="votos">'.$votos_facebook.'&nbsp</span>'; if($votos_facebook == 1) echo 'voto'; else echo 'votos'; ?></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row"> <!-- Sistema de votación -->

                    <span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2">

                        <?php 

                            if($_SESSION['conectado']) for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
                            {
                                echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$id_cancion.'" value="'.$i.'"';
                                echo ($i == $nota) ? " checked><i></i>" : "><i></i>";  
                            }

                        ?>

                    </span>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php
    }

?>
```

Que se vería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me había hecho un lio con la estructura, olvida el comentario y la respuesta que he puesto, ya la he eliminado. Supongo que `<!-- Información (con clasificación) -->` esta dentro de un for y cada bloque implica una canción diferente. Por lo que estoy viendo si que debería sacarte el nombre de la canción y autor pertinentes. Sigo mirando....

Comment: Sí, todo el HTML está incluido en un `foreach` que recorre un `array` obtenido de la base de datos. Edito y añado el contenedor al completo. La solución que me diste con `idCancion` funciona, pero no serviría para el nombre del artista.

Comment: La solucion que te di te puede funcionar, pero esta basada en una idea erronea. Ademas con los autores no te vale ponerlos como id por que se podrian repetir y tendrian que ser como una clase y quedarte con el primero que encuentras. ¿Podrías probar a crear un `div` vació sin clases que englobe toda la estructura de cada canción?

Comment: ¿Equivalente a éste: `<div class="row pt-2"> <!-- Portada, información y sistema de votación -->`?

Comment: uno que englobe todo eso: `<div><div class="row pt-2"> <!-- Portada, información y sistema de votación --> ... </div></div>`

Comment: Genial, con ese mínimo cambio ya funciona como espero. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora solo me falta averiguar por que pasa eso.... Y perdona por la respuesta equivocada!

Comment: Javier, te invito a que publiques la solución como una respuesta y no como una edición a tu pregunta. Es la forma correcta de hacerlo según las sugerencias de la comunidad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es el `.parents()` que devuelve una lista con todos los padres.

Con el siguiente snippet se puede ver el problema, se colorean los hermanos de esos `.parents()` cuando solo te interesa que se coloreen los que están a su nivel.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 $(".row").css("background-color","white")
 console.log("Parent ID:"+$(this).parent('.row').attr("id"));
  $(this).parents(".row").siblings('.row').css("background-color","yellow")
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row > .row {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="song" class="row">
    Grupo 1
    <div id="desc" class="row">
      Hermano - grupo 1
    </div>
    <div id="votes" class="row">
      Hermano - grupo 1
      <button>
        CLICK
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="song2" class="row">
    Grupo 2
    <div id="desc2" class="row">
      Hermano - grupo 2
    </div>
    <div id="votes2" class="row">
      Hermano - grupo 2
      <button>
        CLICK
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

En tu caso tienes varios padres que coinciden con que tienen la clase `.row`

Por lo que para moverte hasta el punto que quieres lo podrías hacer concatenando varios `.parent()`

```
var cancion = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.row').find('.cancion').html();
```

Comment: En efecto, mucho mejor así que la "ñapa" del `div` vacío. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO:

Englobando `<div class="row pt-2"> <!-- Portada, información y sistema de votación -->` en un simple `<div>` vacío como me ha sugerido @x3k_js ya funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]